# How to copy files from projects artifact to another project using cicd

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

i go a CICD that make an artifact and save them in public folder
i need to copy some files of these artifacts to another project
what script i can't use or what the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you want to copy file into another gitlab project.
Once artifact is built in a job, in a stage (ie : build), it will be available in all jobs of the next stage (ie : deploy).

```
build-artifact:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build artifact"
  artifacts:
    name: "public"
    paths:
      - "public/"

deploy_artifact:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd public/   # here are your artifact files.
    - ls -l
    - cd ..
    # now implement copy strategy, 
    # for example in a git repo :
    - git clone https://myusername:mypassord@myrepo.gitlab.com/mygroup/another_project.git
    - cd another_project
    - cp ../public/source_file ./target_file
    - git add target_file
    - git commit -m "added generated file"
    - git push
```

If your destination is not a git repository, you can simply replace by a scp directly to server, or any other copy strategy, directly in the script.

Another way to do it is to get the last artifact of project A, inside the ci of Project B.
Please see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#retrieve-job-artifacts-for-other-projects

Answer (score 0):

When you do trigger to downstream pipelines, just use needs from job that push artifacts, then it will be passed to downstream.

Comment: " artifacts:
    paths:
      - public/"
this is how it look at end of CICD

Comment: can you write an example, i dont understand what you mean